# EC2 Ubuntu Instance Occasional Downtime

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

i'm having trouble with an EC2 instance experiencing a long period (several hours) of downtime every day

- instance type: t1.micro
- availability zone: ap-southeast-2a
- security groups: allow all ICMP, ssh (22) and http (80)
- AMI: based on Ubuntu Server 12.04.3 LTS Server - ami-3d128f07 (64-bit)
- software: openssh, nginx, gunicorn, django

cloudwatch metrics all look good: cpu, memory, disk, etc. and ec2 status check is 2/2 checks passed

i can still ping the machine however i can't reach it over http or ssh

once i can login to ssh (probably after a restart), where would be the best place (log, etc.) to check what is going on during those periods of downtime? everything in the syslog seems fine and dandy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so this way a tricky one. i'd set up my security groups for the ec2 instance so that it only accepted connections from 203.0.0.0/8 ip addresses. this means that it would work sometimes (when my ip address fell in that range) and not others. now that i've changed this back to 0.0.0.0/0, it's all back up and working fine!